# Android, Intent doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm working on an app for my school, but I can't go on my display.class with an intent... I don't know why it doesn't work. Nothing is happening when I click on the button to go to the other class.

Here is how I create intent to go to display activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(CameraTestActivity.this, display.class);
startActivity(i);
```

And my AndroidManifest

```
<activity 
    android:name=".display" > 
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

My **display** activity:

```
package net.sourceforge.zbar.android.CameraTest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class display extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.display); 
    } 
}
```

Thank you

Edit:

Intent seems to work, but nothing happened on my phone's screen

[2015-01-08 10:15:14 - Consomattionchecker] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=net.sourceforge.zbar.android.CameraTest/.CameraTestActivity }

Edit2 : CameraTestActivity code

```
    public class CameraTestActivity extends Activity
{
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private Handler autoFocusHandler;

    TextView scanText;
    Button scanButton;

    ImageScanner scanner;

    private boolean barcodeScanned = false;
    private boolean previewing = true;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("iconv");
    } 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        autoFocusHandler = new Handler();
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        /* Instance barcode scanner */
        scanner = new ImageScanner();
        scanner.setConfig(0, Config.X_DENSITY, 3);
        scanner.setConfig(0, Config.Y_DENSITY, 3);

        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);

        scanText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scanText);

        scanButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ScanButton);

        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (barcodeScanned) {
                        barcodeScanned = false;
                        scanText.setText("Scanning...");
                        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCb);
                        mCamera.startPreview();
                        previewing = true;
                        mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);

                        //------------- try 
                        Intent i = new Intent(CameraTestActivity.this, display.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        //-------------


                    }
                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera();
    }

    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e){
        }
        return c;
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            previewing = false;
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    private Runnable doAutoFocus = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (previewing)
                    mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
            }
        };

    PreviewCallback previewCb = new PreviewCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

                Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
                barcode.setData(data);

                int result = scanner.scanImage(barcode);

                if (result != 0) {
                    previewing = false;
                    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                    mCamera.stopPreview();

                    SymbolSet syms = scanner.getResults();
                    for (Symbol sym : syms) {
                        scanText.setText("Valeur retournée " + sym.getData());
                        //----------
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = sym.getData();
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();



                        //----------
                        barcodeScanned = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

    // Mimic continuous auto-focusing
    AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCB = new AutoFocusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                autoFocusHandler.postDelayed(doAutoFocus, 1000);
            }
        };
}
```

Comment: Post your code of `display` class

Comment: @Rhood please edit your question and send your code to your question

Comment: Post your `CameraTestActivity` class.

Comment: @Rhood Check my Edit in my answer..

Comment: @Rhood learn to accept and upvote answers if they're helpful... that encourages us to help others!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` I can only see `android:name=".display"`

You must also add another activity in it

```
<activity

 android:name=".CameraTestActivity">
</activity>
```

And one more thing just to make you clear,

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyCurrenctActivity.this, ActivityIwantToMoveTo.class); // replace the names of your activities accordingly.
```

**EDIT**

You have set `private boolean barcodeScanned = false`

```
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (barcodeScanned) { // this if block never gets executed since barcodeScanned is false
                    barcodeScanned = false;
                    scanText.setText("Scanning...");
                    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCb);
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                    previewing = true;
                    mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);

                    //------------- try 
                    Intent i = new Intent(CameraTestActivity.this, display.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    //-------------


                }
            }
        });
```

change `barcodeScanned` to `true`

```
private boolean barcodeScanned = true;
```

This was your basic mistake

Comment: I have another activity.

Comment: Did you add that `another activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml` ??

Comment: yes, it's here
`<activity android:name=".CameraTestActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".display" > 
        </activity> `

Comment: For anyone to help you better, Post the entire code for your `CameraTestActivity` class .. Hopefully after that we will be able to diagnose the problem

Answer (score 0):

According to your code your Launcher activity should b CameraTestActivity and second activity should n display so your manifest file should b like

```
 <activity 
        android:name=".CameraTestActivity" > 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".display" >  
   </activity>
```